# Python Pandas, how can I merge 2 columns of a csv taking only the values ​valued?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I haven't been able to create a column for 2 days starting from 2 columns inside a CSV file; my interest is to create a third column by taking the values ​​of the 2 columns:

Example:

```
Column        | NUMBER 1 | NUMBER 2 | NUMBER 3 | NUMBER 4 | NUMBER 5 |
                                                   YES        NaN
                                                   NaN         YES
                                                   NO         NaN
                                                   YES        NaN

Column | NUMBER 6 |
           YES
           YES
           NO
           YES
```

I have tried

```py
df['Number6'] = df['Number4'].fillna(df['Number5'])
```

but I have only value of Number4 column.

where is the error?

Thanks a lot

Marco

Comment: CAn you give us `df` in a way we can understand? Also, what do you mean by :taking the values of the 2 columns? In a tuple? a logical AND?

Comment: could you explain better what would you like to get? Do you wanna fill the values NAN with the values of column 4 or 5?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the error. You code seems and works fine for me.

Comment: when I use the command   df['Number6'] = df['Number4'].fillna(df['Number5'])   the result is :       NUMBER 6 with value YES  - NaN - NO - YES ... the egual value of column NUMBER 4

Comment: Is df a dataframe ?

Answer (score 1):

I used your sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[ 'YES',  np.nan ], [ np.nan, 'YES' ],
    [ 'NO',   np.nan ], [ 'YES',  np.nan ]],
    columns=['Number4', 'Number5'])
```

Then I executed your instruction:

```
df['Number6'] = df['Number4'].fillna(df['Number5'])
```

and I got just your expected result:

```
  Number4 Number5 Number6
0     YES     NaN     YES
1     NaN     YES     YES
2      NO     NaN      NO
3     YES     NaN     YES
```

I'm using *Python 3.7* and *Jupyter Notebook*. Maybe you should upgrade
your installation?

I noticed also that your heading contains e.g. *NUMBER 4* not *Number4*.
Did you write correct column names?

Comment: it is indeed a mystery, it is as if he could not read the will of the second column that is passed to him;
I did a further test by passing the instruction this way:                                                                   df['Number6'] = df['Number5'].fillna(df['Number4']) .... Now I have in Columns[Number6] only the value present in columns Number5...   The dataframe is a CSV, where the field in the column is empty a blank value is passed; could this be the problem?

Comment: Perform the first test without reading any CSV. Just execute my code and check whether you have the same result. I suppose that there is something wrong with the way you read your CSV.